# Story about a woman who sells supplies to people in other worldlines

Tags: story-identification

It was a short story, most likely in a 1950s magazine. In it, survivors of a nuclear war are building a spaceship to leave the planet, and their only source of good supplies is an old woman who drives her truck from our worldline to theirs. I remember one guy tries to hide in her truck, but when she comes back to our world the truck disappears under him. At the end when they leave, the lady mentally searches other realities until she finds one where the ship crashed and they are stuck buying supplies from her.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_Market_(short_story)

I am pretty sure this was the story. Time travel is involved. The old woman is sort of a jerk, exploiting the survivors and also not worried about what will happen to her in the future, just wants to make money in the present.

Comment: Yes! I was able to confirm that that is the story - Captive Market by Philip K. Dick in IF: Worlds of Science Fiction, April 1955. Thanks!

Comment: @UnknownOrbits if this is the story please click on the tick mark to the left of this answer to mark is as accepted. Thanks :-)